# Bulk upload to Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I need to insert data on daily basis to AWS Redshift. 
The requirement is to analyze only the daily batch inserted to Redshift. Redshift cluster is used by BI tools for analytics.

Question:

What are the best practices to "renew" the data set on a daily basis?
My concern is it is a quite heavy operation and performance will be poor but at the same time it is a quite common situation and I believe it was done before by multiple organization.

Comment: Please amend your question to give more detail. 1)how many rows approx? 2) what size cluster approx? 3) how is your data organised? many tables? 1 table? sort keys? dist keys? 4) what is your current method of bulk upload? 5) what sort of queries do you run on the tables? what joins? what filters? 6) how many queries / day 7) how fast do you need the queries to return?

Comment: What do you mean by "renew"? Do you just want to load the data from Amazon S3 into an empty table, or are you trying to do insert/updates (upserts)?

Comment: Hi John.
data volume is around 10TB. yes, it is on s3 and Redshift is a multi-tenant environment analyzing data via BI tools.  each day new batch 10TB need to be loaded to Redshift.
  
For the reason, the Redshift cluster is used  I don't know what is the best way to "renew" data every day.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is on S3, why not create an [`EXTERNAL TABLE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html) over it. Then if the query speed over external table it not enough you can load it using [`CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_AS.html) statement into a temporary table, and once loaded, rename to a name your usual table name.

Sketched SQL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE external_daily_batch_20190422 (
    <schema ...>
)
PARTITIONED BY (
    <if anything to partition on>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE <data format>
LOCATION 's3://my-s3-location/2019-04-22';


CREATE TABLE internal_daily_batch_temp 
    DISTKEY ...
    SORTKEY ...
AS 
SELECT * from external_daily_batch_20190422;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS internal_daily_batch__backup CASCADE;


ALTER TABLE internal_daily_batch rename to internal_daily_batch__backup;


ALTER TABLE internal_daily_batch_temp rename to internal_daily_batch;
```

---

#### Incremental load not possible?

By the way, is all of your 10TB of data mutable? Isn't incremental update possible?